# RIA Services extract - Sort/Filter/Group/Page Descriptors + stored procedure

Tags: wcf-ria-services

When I have a difficult query I normally write a T-SQL view and register the view inside Entity framework.  This allows me to push composing the descriptors on top of my view to RIA services.

With my current problem creating a view is not possible. (at least it is not obvious - attached is screenshot of the query - nested parameterized query - I also make use of several functions inside SUM).

[image: nested parameterized query]

Question 1:
How would I EXTRACT the **metadata** that RIA Services uses so I can pass the information to a stored procedure that uses Common Table Expressions to filter the result set manually?

I'm not sure where to look inside "this" on the LinqToEntitiesDomainService class.
I'm hoping there is an easy way then parsing HttpContext querystring/post values.

Question 2:
After I have the descriptors and sp returns the correct result sets.  How can I tell ria services to longer compose the query after I return the correct data?

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the query to create the view.

I removed the where clause on inner query and instead added a group by DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.ticketstart), 0)  so i could expose date for filtering in my outer query.

if i ever do need this I will probably use plain old wcf and copy the ideas from: http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/10-01-14/how-to-server-sorting-filtering-grouping-and-paging-with-radgridview-for-silverlight-without-wcf-ria-services.aspx